# iOS fails to upload a local wav file to my server

Tags: php, objective-c, file-transfer, asiformdatarequest

I'm making an app with which the user can record sound and send it to my server. The first part works perfectly. I can record and play the sound. The problem is however that when i try to upload the wav file that is the result of this recording to my server it will not accept any thing that is longer than 2 minutes and a couple of seconds (about 2 MB) smaller files are sent and handled correctly. Any bigger than that results in sending the request but not attaching the file, or attaching the file but the server can't read it. The first would seem more likely to me. My Objective-c code is as follows:

**OBJECTIVE-C CODE**

```
NSString *theUrl = @"http://www.myserver.nl";
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]];

[request setFile:[soundFileURL path] forKey:@"mainfile"]; //The file gets added
[request startSynchronous]; //Request is being sent.
```

Any thoughts or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's upload limits are governed by a few settings:

[upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
[memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)
[post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

There's also web-server limits, like Apache's [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) that can kick in long before PHP's do.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use asynchronous transfer. You can then hook some logging or a UIProgressBar to ASIFormDataRequest's progressDelegate property so that ASI can report its upload progress, so you can see if it's pooping out from the app side.

My suspicion, though, is that you're running afoul of the "max upload size" configuration on the server. Are you sending this to code you wrote? I use PHP mostly on the server side, and I know beyond a certain size that's specified in the php.ini file, it just barfs.

Comment: The max upload size fixed it, dumb of me to not think of that... Sorry for the lame question and thanks for the quick reply! :)

Comment: Actually the reply Marc B gave is 'more correct' as the post_max_size and memory_limit had to be increased aswell. I'll give the best answer to him :)

Comment: @dragon112 *Fiiiiiine*! ;-) I still recommend asynchronous connections, and not only because you can monitor they're progress.

Comment: I know, I'm planning to change it to asynchronous. This is just a test :)